# Connecting D-LINK DSL 225 to a MULTILAYER SWITCH

Tags: networking, router, routing

I want to connect a home router D-link DSL 225 to a multilayer switch, so computers connected to switch will be able to get to the internet.

The router ip (DG) is 10.0.0.138.

The router is connected to the switch to Gi0/3, i configured the port ip of the switch to 10.0.0.137.

I configured vlan 10 to IP address 192.168.10.1 and i have one computer connected to it in Gi0/0 the computer ip is 192.168.10.10.

I managed to do ping **from the switch CLI** to the router IP i even managed to ping 8.8.8.8.

I only have problem to ping from the computer to the Router IP (10.0.0.138) and of course to 8.8.8.8.

i can only ping from the computer to 10.0.0.137 (port Gi0/3)

The router is in its default settings (i reset it), i only changed the DG IP.

some one helped me and told me to add a static route in the router but he didn't gave me instructions to do that.

so i added static route in the router:

```
IP Version: IPv4

Destination IP/prefix length: 192.168.10.10/32

Interface: LAN/br0

Gateway:10.0.0.138
```

so now i can ping from the computer to 10.0.0.138 but i still can't reach 8.8.8.8.

I only want to ask is it possible to do that or i am waseting my time? or there is something i need to configure in the router?

My network (the d-link model is dsl 225 and not 615):
[image]

my switch config:

```
spanning-tree mode pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id
!
vlan internal allocation policy ascending
!
vlan 10
 name comp
!
vlan 100
 name VLAN100
!
vlan 200,300
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 switchport access vlan 10
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/2
 media-type rj45
 negotiation auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/3
 no switchport
 ip address 10.0.0.137 255.255.255.0
 negotiation auto
!
interface Vlan10
 ip address 192.168.10.1 255.255.255.0
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.0.0.138
!
!
!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The router *requires* a route to the 192.168.10.0/24 network. You need to set up a static route on the router, pointing 192.168.10.0/24 to 10.0.0.137 as gateway.

Without that static route, any packet that the router is trying to send to the remote VLAN is sent using the default route = towards the Internet.

Comment: Thank you , its still not working, i can only ping 10.0.0.138 and not 8.8.8.8. maybe this router dose'nt support NAT static route, i understand that it can be the problem.